# Join Two COUNT() in one SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following Oracle SQL Query:

```
SELECT ST.hrs_source_id, 
       TT.hrs_source_name, 
       Count(*) 
FROM   ps_hrs_app_profile P, 
       ps_hrs_rcmnt_sts S, 
       ps_hrs_al_log_srce ST, 
       ps_hrs_source TT 
WHERE  ST.hrs_source_id = TT.hrs_source_id 
       AND P.hrs_person_id = S.hrs_person_id 
       AND P.hrs_al_log_id = ST.hrs_al_log_id 
       AND S.status_code = '010' 
       AND S.status_dt BETWEEN '01-JAN-09' AND '31-MAR-16' 
GROUP  BY ST.hrs_source_id, 
          TT.hrs_source_name 
ORDER  BY TT.hrs_source_name ASC;
```

The above query produces results with 3 columns: `HRS_SOURCE_ID`, `HRS_SOURCE_NAME`, `COUNT`. But I want to join two `COUNT`s into one query. The second query is identical as above, but only `STATUS_CODE` should be equal to '060', while in first query its equal to '010'. How to join two `COUNT`s together in one Query, so total will be 4 columns? Please help to solve it.

Comment: As an aside, please, please, PLEASE fix your `AND S.status_dt BETWEEN '01-JAN-09' AND '31-MAR-16'` so that Oracle doesn't have to implicitly convert your string into a date. And dates have four digit years. You're after something like: `AND S.status_dt BETWEEN to_date('01/01/2009', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('31/03/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy')`. Also, please note that if your status_dt column contains times other than midnight, you will exclude anything after 31st March at midnight. I.e. a row with a status_dt of `31/03/2016 00:00:01` won't be included in the results your query.

Answer (score 8):

You can use a case expression to get the different counts:

```
SELECT ST.HRS_SOURCE_ID, 
       TT.HRS_SOURCE_NAME, 
       COUNT(case when S.STATUS_CODE = '060' then 1 end) as cnt60, 
       count(case when S.STATUS_CODE = '010' then 1 end) as cnt10
FROM PS_HRS_APP_PROFILE P, PS_HRS_RCMNT_STS S, PS_HRS_AL_LOG_SRCE ST, PS_HRS_SOURCE TT
WHERE ST.HRS_SOURCE_ID = TT.HRS_SOURCE_ID
   AND P.HRS_PERSON_ID = S.HRS_PERSON_ID
   AND P.HRS_AL_LOG_ID = ST.HRS_AL_LOG_ID
   AND (S.STATUS_CODE = '010' or S.STATUS_CODE = '060')
   AND S.STATUS_DT BETWEEN '01-JAN-09' AND '31-MAR-16'
GROUP BY ST.HRS_SOURCE_ID, TT.HRS_SOURCE_NAME
ORDER BY TT.HRS_SOURCE_NAME ASC
```

Notice the OR in the where clause.

You may better understand a sum combined with count:

```
sum(case when S.STATUS_CODE = '060' then 1 else 0 end) cnt60
```

To explain the case in the query, there is no `else`. If status is different from 060 then the value returned by case is `null`. Null is not counted by `count`.